# Is it possible to retrieve several Blobs from Azure Blob Storage in a single API invocation?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I would like to retrieve the content of several BLOBs stored in Azure Blob Storage Service using a single API. 
All these BLOBs share the same security policy and Access Token.

Is is possible using the .NET SDK?

Thanks

cghersi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't find any single API or SDK operation to achieve this according to the document.

See [Get Blob API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob).
We can only get one blob content for each single request. As for SDK operation, the [Download methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblob?view=azure-dotnet) are based on that rest api.

We can get all blob references in one container using `ListBlobs` method of CloudBlobContainer([one single list blobs api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs)), but for their contents it requires download method as well.